# who is responsible for server monitoring?

Tags: java, performance

who is responsible for server monitoring ?

development team ? development team leader ?
Project manager ?
dba ?
infrastructure team ?

who is responsible when application server is running slow or not responding ?

what tools are available for tomcat monitoring ?

Comment: Ask your boss, that is different in different organisations with different needs.

Comment: This is at least two separate questions, both of which (IMV) belong over on http://serverfault.com. It's also a "how long is a piece of string" question.

Comment: It doesn't belong here either. The answer depends on the organisation.

Answer (score 5):

> who is responsible for server monitoring ?

Define "monitoring".

> development team ?

Yes.  They should be looking at the application server.

> development team leader ?

Yes.

> Project manager ?

Maybe.

> dba ?

For database server, yes.

> infrastructure team ?

Yes; overall server health.  "Server" means the hardware and virtual machine on which the application server is deployed.

> who is responsible when application
>   server is running slow or not
>   responding ?

Depends on the root cause.

> what tools are available for tomcat
>   monitoring ?

Depends on where you want to apply them: aspects in apps, commercial monitoring tools if you mean the server, etc.

Comment: Also define "server"; our monitoring team here gets that so massively wrong it's embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

at my shop, dev are the only ones that can handle server outages, support sometimes becomes aware of issues before development. lead dev is responsible when the application server is down.

see thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242958/best-tools-to-monitor-tomcat for monitoring info, seems that one popular answer is JavaMelody, http://javamelody.googlecode.com

Answer (score 0):

> who is responsible for server monitoring ?

Hard to say without any information. If you're a team of one, the answer is obvious.

Here, the development servers are usually monitored by the developers while test and production systems are monitored by the admins.

> who is responsible when application server is running slow or not responding ?

Someone with the necessary knowledge needs to check the server to see what's the problem. Is the system swapping? Add more RAM. Is the CPU 100% busy? Check for bugs in the code and memory leaks (GC often causes this behavior). Is there enough RAM and the CPU is bored to death? Maybe the DB is too slow or some network connection is congested (the "tubes" are too tight).